# VBA : close 1 Excel file but not another and go on with code

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 Excel file with VBA code and it has to run multiple other Excel files WBK9 & WBK10. Those other Excel Files have at the end :

```vb
    If application.workbooks.count = 1 then
        application.quit
    else
        thisworkbook.close
    end if
```

So WBK9 and WBK10 will close; but the first Excel file will not close.
But I want the first Excel file to continue with its code; but it doesn't continue. The code in the first Excel file is:

```vb
    Set WBK9 = Workbooks.Open("XXXXXX.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) 
            WBK9.Activate
            
                         
    Set WBK10 = Workbooks.Open("YYYYY.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) 
            WBK10.Activate
```

-> but after the "WBK9.Activate" (and when WBK9 closes) it doesn't continue with WBK10. What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: From the code you've posted I'd say it's impossible to see what you're trying to do.  What's the VBA code in your _1 Excel file with VBA_?  Does code in WBK9 & 10 fire when it opens?  You say there's code at the end, but at the end of what?  End of the first procedure you wrote / end of the `Workbook_Close` event procedure?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. So : my first Excel file, we will say WST1, has a macro : 

  Set WBK9 = Workbooks.Open("XXXXXX.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) 
            WBK9.Activate            
                         
    Set WBK10 = Workbooks.Open("YYYYY.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) 
            WBK10.Activate

About WBK9 & WBK10 : they have a macro such that when you open it, that it runs automatically a macro to update the file with information. But at the end of WBK9 & 10, there is code to automatically close this Excel file when it has finished to run the macro

Comment: But I want after that WBK9 run its macro & closes, that afterwards WST1 automatically opens WBK10 (which will also run its own macro & close). But at the moment WST1 opens WBK9. But after that WBK9 closes, the macro in WST1 doesn't continue with WBK10